# JSF with redis for session management

Tags: nginx, tomcat, jsf, redis, load-balancing

I'm trying to use redis to store http sessions, because I want to use a load balancer to distribute the request between two servers (without sticky sessions).
Currently, I'm using redisson (https://redisson.org/) with the tomcat configuration (https://redisson.org/articles/redis-based-tomcat-session-management.html) and nginx for load balancing.

Redisson configuration in both tomcats:

```
<Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager"
        configPath="${catalina.base}/conf/redisson.yaml" 
        readMode="MEMORY" updateMode="AFTER_REQUEST" broadcastSessionEvents="false"
        broadcastSessionUpdates="true"
        keyPrefix=""/>
```

In jsf:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

NGINX:

```
upstream samplecluster {
  server localhost:9090;
  server localhost:8080;
}

server {
 listen 4040;       
 server_name localhost;
 
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://samplecluster;
  }
}
```

I use, viewscoped beans.
The problem is that when the different actions of the bean are distributed, sometimes data get lost. For example, from the main screen I open a modal to select specific data. That data, after being selected, should be shown in them main screen.
That's not happening, the data get lost.

What could be wrong?

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with Redisson, so I built my own Redis based Tomcat Session Manager: https://github.com/exabrial/redex-sm . It has a lot of advantages including being simpler and faster. You might give it a try!

Comment: The docs explain that it only has been tested with sticky sessions, is that right? I don't want to use sticky sessions because I need to do zero downtime deployments.

Comment: Those two things are not mutually exclusive. A sticky session sends the person back to the same server _unless_ that server is down, then it picks a new server :) So you will absolutely have zero-downtime deployments. This is how we continuously deploy to production without downtime.

Comment: I added the explanation to the readme of why sticky sessions are a good thing.

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher great, I've been reading about sticky sessions but the thing is that if I use ip-hash for that, the load balancing wouldn't be fair. Is it possible to do fair distribution using sticky sessions with nginx?

Comment: The Nginix guys thought of that too :) The algorithm hashes the IP or TLS session id. It then does a mod operation by the number of backend servers available in the pool. This evenly distributes inbound load across the backends. As servers come and go from the pool, it automatically distributes the load on them evenly.

Comment: Yes, but what about when you have  a lot of users with the same IP?

Comment: In that case, use `hash $remote_addr$remote_port` or `hash $ssl_session_id` or some combination to that includes at least one unique variable

Comment: Let me know if that all works and dont forget to vote/accept my answer, I'm trying to get to mod status, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I have a question with this. If I have 5 servers, when one server goes down because of a deploy, the users on that server would move to another. When that server goes up (deploy finished) is there a way to route users back to it?

Comment: That depends entirely on your load balancer. We use haproxy (instead of nginix) and it does this. I'd actually recommend haproxy over nginix as it's better suited for load balancing in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to do session replication, you *should* probably be using server side state saving.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The reason being is MyFaces and other JSF implementations often generate encryption keys for encrypting/signing the state on the client side. You would have to manage and synchronize these keys across your servers in order for this to work perfectly.

`server` works better in my opinion, and since you have a session anyway, you might as well use it!

Comment: I tried with server side but the problem persists

Comment: Sorry to hear that, can you post your ngix balance config, your context.xml, and your web.xml?

Comment: yes, already posted

Comment: you definitely need to add `<distributable />` to the web.xml. I'm beginning to think the issue may not be replication however, but with your code. 

I would start by removing the cachefilter, securityfilter, etc one by one and see if that fixes the problem. If it does not, drop down to one server and connect directly and see if you can reproduce the error. I'm guessing you are storing some state somewhere _else_ other than the session... maybe in a threadlocal or static variable?

Comment: also post some of @ViewScoped beans (including imports) that are having trouble

Comment: also are you seeing sessions go into Redis? I use TablePlus to browse my Redis server

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing sessions in redis. If I use only one server it works but when I add a second server it fails.

Comment: At least MyFaces also used encryption per default for server side; so either you disable it (o.a.m.USE_ENCRYPTION=false) or you still need to set encryption keys.
Also note that ViewScoped bean are not encrypted since CDI, only the viewstate itself.